# Can i put a file to an arraylist that does not have string type?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have created a method that reads a file that contains numbers separated with ";",the problem is that the type of the arraylist is not string,so is there any other way that I can put the content of the file in the arraylist without changing its type to string? I also have the class which is the type of the arraylist and I have not filled it yet.

```
public void loadData(String fileName,ArrayList<Records> collection);
    {
            Scanner myFile = new Scanner (new File(fileName)).useDelimiter(";");
            String token = "";
            while(myFile.hasNext()) {
                token = myFile.next();
                collection.add(token);

            }
            myfile.close()




    }

class Records{


}
```

Comment: Yes. You need to *parse* the `String` you read into a `Records`. Without any knowledge of the file, the string or the "records" we can't offer any more than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Records` is not compatible with `String` unless you extend it (which is not possible in this case since `String` is `final`). If you define `List<Records>`, then only *subtypes* of `Records` can be added.

To add a new instance of `Records` to a collection, there must be first a way to resolve `String` and create a new instance of `Records` from it:

```
class Records {
    public Records(String string) { /* your implementation */ }
}
```

Then you do:

```
String token = "";
while (myFile.hasNext()) {
    token = myFile.next();
    collection.add(new Records(token));

}
```